# No Wifi on ubuntu 14.04 in Inspiron 15 5570

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros, inspiron

I am using Dell Inspiron 15 5570 laptop. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (dual OS). Wifi enable option is not listed when clicking Wifi icon. In Windows 10, Wifi is working fine.

Network controller : Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31).

Result of command `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[   19.878601] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   19.879412] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[   20.122393] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122400] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122402] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[   20.122405] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122406] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[   20.122409] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122410] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[   20.122413] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122414] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[   20.122417] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[   20.122418] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[   20.122419] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[   20.122420] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
[   35.594654] audit: type=1400 audit(1516343943.478:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=927 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   35.594657] audit: type=1400 audit(1516343943.478:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=927 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Result of command `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version`:
`Version: 1.127.24`

Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `dmesg | grep ath` and also: `sudo dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep Version` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need much newer firmware! With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /tmp
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working!

Comment: your wifi solution worked like charm! But now I am facing issue with system freezing up after suspend mode. I tried to switch video driver from X.Org to fglrx by AMD graphics accelerator, but even the switch does not happen. Any suggestions regarding this?